# Single word request: of/at that phase/time/period/care/management

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, academic-writing

I am writing a study aim and needs to be really concise. For background, "post-acute care" is the next/second step care in these patients' management. In other words, their care/management has two phases, post-acute is the second phase.

The aim should carry the two meanings: (1) to evaluate post-acute management of these patients and (2) to evaluate these patients' physical therapy use during post-acute management/in the post-acute phase. However, repeating post-acute makes the aim wordy.

What words would be suitable for replacing the question marks?

> To evaluate post-acute management of brain trauma patients and assess their **???** physical therapy use.

My own not so good ideas:

- of that time
- of that phase
- of that place

Comment: The cited duplicate and the previous thread lead to contemporaneous and contemporary. 'Then' as an adjective can also be used. For events close to the present, 'current' is the obvious choice.

Comment: As suggested, the answer can be found here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134874/word-to-mean-then-current